# Adapted ASR-6405E controller losses raid array0 array

Tags: raid0, adaptec

I've goit a Dell R200 server with an adaptec ASR-6405E RAID controller and 2 WD red 4TB drives in a raid-0 array.

The harddisks replaced 2 Seagate 3TB drives 2 years ago because of the same issue.

What happens is that at a certain moment the raid controller looses the raid array, and obviously stops working.
When I run the adaptec tool, I can force the array to come back online, and it runs for a week and than the array was lost again.
Same thing happened with the other array of 3TB before.
I'm running a media check on the drives, which will take quite some time.

So now I could get me some new drives again, but I prefer to understand why this happens.
The drives are being used for a backup server, so during 8 hours a night the drives are being filled with filles, the rest of the day, nothing happens on the server.
Although the drives may be worn out because of the writes, I would not expect that to make the array gets lost.

So I hope someone can give me some advice on how to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Get another (better) controller.

Comment: Hi Sven, 

Is that a (personal) dislike of Adaptec, the model or can you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: Adaptec devices have a bad reputation these days for exactly the kind of errors you describe. Personal (anectotical) experience backs this - I've replaced Adapcted controllers (6405) in multiple servers where the constant trouble with the  array vanished after replacing the controller.

Comment: In the mean time I did some media testing, and it appears that in both cases, only one drive had bad sectors.
Now I'm wondering is that because of the controller or could it be the source that writes to that drive/sectors.

As it's a raid-0 I can't rebuild it after replacing the drive.
So I thought I'd make a disk copy to a single drive, but clonezilla does shows the array, but is showing the message that the drive needs to be unmounted or present in the system.

Do you have some more tips on how to get the data from the forced online array to a single drive?